# Programmatically build a technical drawing

Tags: flutter, dart

I've just spent roughly a week on this task and I'm slowly giving up on this. Basically I'm trying to build a layout for a drawing that will change its size based on selected type of product. It is a really simple drawing... Axe (top container) which is a plain container with white border, fixed width and hight stretch from top of the container to bottom of the wheel. Wheel (bottom container) which is also another container filled white which changes its radiuses fixed size and shape based on selected product. That what I managed to do without any problem. The problem is to add layout for placing dimension annotation to it.

1/ Container for horizontal annotation should change its width based on wheel width

2/ Placing container for wheel height annotation which change its height based on wheel height and container for overall length annotation which will stretch its height from top of the axe container to bottom of wheel container

This is mock-up of what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

Here is my code

```
Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                AxeBuilder(),
                WheelBuilder(
                  wheelType: WheelType.T,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                DimBuilder(
                  plane: Plane.Horizontal,
                  height: 30,
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

And this is what I get

[image]

Any idea what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it and it is horrendous. It still need some polishing but it works. Message to Flutter team : could you include Grid container in flutter for this purposes? (Not a grid view which is already included)

```
Container(
          height: 200,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              IntrinsicWidth(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    AxeBuilder(),
                    WheelBuilder(
                      wheelType: WheelType.T,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    DimBuilder(
                      plane: Plane.Horizontal,
                      height: 25,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    //   width: 30,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: SizedBox(),
                        ),
                        IntrinsicHeight(
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                                child: WheelBuilder(
                                  wheelType: WheelType.T,
                                ),
                              ),
                              DimBuilder(
                                plane: Plane.Vertical,
                                height: 20,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 24,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: DimBuilder(
                    plane: Plane.Vertical,
                    height: 20,
                  )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 24,
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]